# Validating a number in HTML form using jQuery

Tags: jquery

User types a number into an input type="text" tag.  The value must be a positive number, so need to check two things: (a) is it a number? and if so, (b) is it positive?

Here is my code (using jQuery):

```
 $("input:text").change(function() {   
   if ( !$.isNumeric( $(event.target).val() )) {  
      $(this).focus();  
      alert("You must input a number (no text)");  
   }  
   else if ( $(event.target).val() < 0 ) {  
      $(this).focus();  
      alert("You must input a positive number");   
   }  
});
```

This code is placed inside the ready handler so it is standing by to react whenever the user changes the content of a cell.  When a cell's content is changed, the event handler runs when the user clicks outside that text box. If the new value is not a number or is a negative number, focus returns to the problem text box and an alert pops up. That all is working great! However, I have one little problem.

After focus is returned to the problem text box, if the user then clicks somewhere else without making the necessary alteration to the incorrect text, nothing happens and the incorrect text is preserved. The reason is that this time nothing "changed," so the event handler did not react.

Looking for ideas here. How can I lock the user into the problem element, forcing them to fix their mistake before being able to leave that text box? Thank you very much for helping me with this!

============================================================

I just had an idea.  What if I could restore the previous value when the user changes it to something other than a positive number.  In other words, there is a valid number in the cell now but user changes it to text, so the alert pops up and the cell's value reverts to the previous valid number.

The code "$(event.target).val()" grabs the value after the change, but is there some way I can recover the value in that cell before the change?  I could then do 
--> "$(this).val(previous value);" to put it back and replace the improper text.  Any suggestions along this line would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Use `blur` instead of change...

Comment: You could also add the blur event to your code. Plus you could streamline your checks a good deal.

Comment: If you need to support Firefox, you should change `function()` to `function(event)`

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/qx6723gk/

Comment: Great ideas!  Change non-numeric entries to zero, take the minus sign away if negative.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[here's the link](http://jsfiddle.net/bLracu8x/5)

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var number_pat= /^-?(\d+\.?\d*)$|(\d*\.?\d+)$/;
    $("#test").focusout(function(){
        var val=$('#test').val();
        if(val.match(number_pat)==null && val!='')
        {
            alert('input a number(no text)');
            $('#test').addClass('error');
        }
       else if(val<0)
       {
           $('#test').addClass('error');
           alert('input a positive number');
       }
        else
           $('#test').removeClass('error');
    });


});
```

html:

```
<input type="text"  id='test'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parseInt the inserted value and then test it

```
$("input[type=text]").change(function() {   
    var value=parseInt($(this).val());

   if ( !$.isNumeric( value )) {  
      $(this).focus();  
      alert("You must input a number (no text)");  
   }  
   else if ( value < 0 ) {  
      $(this).focus();  
      alert("You must input a positive number");   
   }  
});
```

Find this code in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h5xm1vuj/

Anyway for lots of a useful validation options check [Parsley Validator](http://parsleyjs.org)